# What is the most efficient way to do a ONE:ONE relation on google app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Even with all I do know about the AppEngine datastore, I don't know the answer to this.  I'm trying to avoid having to write and run all the code it would take to figure it out, hoping someone already knows the answer.

I have code like:

```
class AddlInfo(db.Model)
     user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
     otherstuff = db.ListProperty(db.Key, indexed=False)
```

And create the record with:

```
info = AddlInfo(user=user)
info.put()
```

To get this object I can do something like:

```
# This seems excessively wordy (even though that doesn't directly translate into slower)
info = AddlInfo.all().filter('user =', user).fetch(1)
```

or I could do something like:

```
class AddlInfo(db.Model)
     # str(user.key()) is the key to this record
     otherstuff = db.ListProperty(db.Key, indexed=False)
```

Creation looks like:

```
info = AddlInfo(key_name=str(user.key()))
info.put()
```

And then get the info with:

```
info = AddlInfo.get(str(user.key()))
```

I don't need the reference_property in the AddlInfo, (I got there using the user object in the first place).  Which is faster/less resource intensive?

==================

Part of why I was doing it this way is that otherstuff could be a list of 100+ keys and I only need them sometimes (probably less than 50% of the time)  I was trying to make it more efficient by not having to load those 100+ keys on every request.....

Comment: The most efficient way is to just denormalize and not have 2 separate entities.

Comment: there's a "trick" to avoid the overhead you mention at the end - place the 100+ keys in a child class.  then you can select for that, retrieve the key (only), find the parent, and pull the smaller amount of data.  this is described on another answer here, somewhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between those 2 options, the second is marginally cheaper, because you're determining the key by inference rather than looking it up in a remote index.

As Wooble said, it's cheaper still to just keep everything on one entity. Consider an [Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) if you just need a way to store a bunch of optional, ad-hoc properties.

Comment: More than marginally cheaper - about half the cost/time.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the better one, with one modification: There's no need to use the whole key of the user as the key name of this entity - just use the same key name as the User record.

Comment: Turns out you can't use the whole key.  It won't let you.

Comment: @Mark0978 Why not? The only reason I can think of that this would be an issue is if the key you're trying to use is too long.